# Moz padding behaving differently on buttons

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

On all my buttons the padding is behaving differently in firefox. From research I know this is because FF has some strange settings in the default stylesheet but I have added the general fix into my stylesheet.  That's fine and I can live with that apart from one button will not fit into the toolbar in firefox because the padding makes it too big.

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QRbUv/).

Usual fix;

```
input[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner{padding:0; border:0;}
```

The css for the button with a few things removed;

```
.buttonBlue {background-color:#008abd; border-radius:0.2em; 
             font-family:inherit; 
             color:white; border: 1px solid black;
             cursor:pointer; 


             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#008abd', endColorstr='#036b91');
             background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#008abd), to(#036b91));
             background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #008abd,  #036b91);


    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe use a <button> element instead? That would hopefully style more consistently for you cross-browser.

Comment: Has no effect and still the same problem but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set an element's appearance attribute to none, any well-behaved browser will drop its gui flavor.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance

For buttons, the default value for appearance is "button". Setting it to "none" explicitely should override the browser's built-in platform-native styling, including weird padding.

Firefox is not the only browser reacting to this attribute: Safari and Chrome listen to the -webkit-appearance variation, and Opera listens to the -o-appearance variation. I don't know about MSIE9 or 10.

Comment: This does not make any difference at all. I honestly thought it would and I even tried setting it to important in the css but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix by targeting moz with a css prefix. It's not ideal but it works and I need to move onto other things rather than worrying about a button! Here it is anyway.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
                           .buttonBlue 
                             { padding:0px 7px 0px 4px !important;} 
                            }
```